# How can I click the login button on the tinder login page?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to log into Tinder but I can't access the log in button

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
url = "https://tinder.com/"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

log_in = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="s-1432688076"]/div/div[1]/div/div/main/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/button[2]')
log_in.click()
```

I'm getting this error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="s-1432688076"]/div/div[1]/div/div/main/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/button[2]"}
  (Session info: chrome=111.0.5563.65)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    (No symbol) [0x0078DCE3]
    (No symbol) [0x007239D1]
    (No symbol) [0x00634DA8]
    (No symbol) [0x0066019F]
    (No symbol) [0x006603AB]
    (No symbol) [0x0068EE62]
    (No symbol) [0x0067AF14]
    (No symbol) [0x0068D57C]
    (No symbol) [0x0067ACC6]
    (No symbol) [0x00656F68]
    (No symbol) [0x006580CD]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00A03832+2506274]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00A39794+2727300]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00A3E36C+2746716]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00836690+617600]
    (No symbol) [0x0072C712]
    (No symbol) [0x00731FF8]
    (No symbol) [0x007320DB]
    (No symbol) [0x0073C63B]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x753EFA29+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x76FB7A9E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x76FB7A6E+238]

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following XPath expression:  `//div[text()='Log in']`

```
log_in = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[text()="Log in"]')
log_in.click()
```

Assuming the desired element is this:

[image]

**On another note, suggestion:** Use `waits` rather than `time.sleep` as a best practice. `waits` are much more smarter than `time.sleep`.

Replace below code:

```
time.sleep(5)
log_in = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[text()="Log in"]')
log_in.click()
```

to below:

```
log_in = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Log in']")))
log_in.click()
```

You will need these imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
```